# Hibernate inheritance issues when batch inserting

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

I have a class that extends another one (both entities). The parent and child share the same primary key

I'm trying to insert in batch 20k rows (of child entity), using **saveAll** method of **spring-jpa repository**, but checking the log you can see it's
executing 40k batches. I was expecting that it would insert ALL the parents then ALL the children as an optimization or somehow.

There is no batch at all.

*parent*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Order implements Serializable {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sq_order_gen", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "sq_order")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sq_order_gen")
@Column(name = "order_id")
private Long id;
```

*child*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders_infos")
public class OrderInfos extends Order implements Serializable {
```

Logs of inserting

```
2021-12-22 09:44:57.485  INFO [testBE,deabba7e41a880a1,deabba7e41a880a1,true] 37668 --- [nio-8198-exec-6] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    3149500 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    1255278700 nanoseconds spent preparing 40002 JDBC statements;
    91509100 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
    163476681800 nanoseconds spent executing 40000 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    223333492400 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 20000 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

Is there any workaround?

env: Springboot 2.3.9 with spring jpa -> Hibernate **5.4.29**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

I see a similarity in this post
https://stchedroff.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/jpa-hibernate-object-inheritance-batch-insert/

Comment: Hello @Mike, have you managed to solve the issue? I am experiencing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Hello because of this issue, I had to change the entities using @MapsId
and one-to-one) so no inheritance